# How to find an element based on a two data-attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
 <ul>
    <li id="RadListBox1_i2" class="rlbItem ui-draggable">

        <div class="ui-draggable ui-state-default" data-shortid="1007">
        <em>ProductId: </em>
        <span>110-01-070-10</span>
        <br>
        <em>ShortID: </em>
        <span class="ShortID" data-shortid="1007">1007</span>
        <br>
        <em>Product Defaul cat: </em>
        <span class="spanDefCat" data-defcat="334">334</span>
        </div>
        </span>
        </li>
        <li id="RadListBox1_i3" class="rlbItem ui-draggable">
        <li id="RadListBox1_i4" class="rlbItem ui-draggable">

    </ul>
```

I need to find this element i was using this function before

```
$("#AllProducts li:contains('ShortID:" + Product + "'):contains('" + iCategory + "')").addClass("backDefaultCat");
```

But now as you see i working with data-shortid=X sow i need to check if item have data-shortid=X and data-defcat=Y

some think like this

```
  $("span.ShortID[data-shortid=" + Product + "] span.spanDefCat[data-defcat=" + iCategory + "]").parents("li:first").addClass("backDefaultCat");
```

I just can combine it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("#AllProducts li").filter(function(){
    return $(this).has('[data-shortid="' + Product + '"]').length > 0 && $(this).has('[data-defcat="' + iCategory + '"]').length > 0
}).addClass("backDefaultCat");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SBhMV/)

Or

```
$('#AllProducts li:has(span.ShortID[data-shortid="' + Product + '"]):has(span.spanDefCat[data-defcat="' + iCategory + '"])').addClass("backDefaultCat");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SBhMV/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace with below line. Just added `,` which you forgot :)

```
$("span.ShortID[data-shortid=" + Product + "], span.spanDefCat[data-shortid=" + iCategory + "]").parents("li:first").addClass("backDefaultCat");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SBhMV/7/

updated your `jsFiddle` please check.

http://jsfiddle.net/SBhMV/9/

Updated once again

Comment: Added each loop. Please check

Comment: Thx just a small error  the second data of span is data-defcat not shortid i eddited my code ,@Arun because of this it's fail

Comment: @rajni just change the second data to data-defcat